# Searching for a keyword inside a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to search for a keyword in a list and display all the list item's positions that match said keyword. I've not managed to mind anything helpful yet and was wondering if anyone can help me out, here's the code I have currently

```
import os
directory = os.listdir()
print(directory)
pyFilename = '.py'
if pyFilename in directory:
        print("working")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [list comprehenssions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
import os
pyFilename = '.py'
directory = [(position, filename) for position, filename in enumerate(os.listdir()) 
             if filename.endswith(pyFilename)]
print(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
directory = os.listdir()
print(directory)
pyFilename = '.py'

list_location = 0
for z in directory:
    if pyFilename in z:
        print("working: list location %s" % list_location)

    list_location = list_location + 1
```

Comment: Learn to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).